# nodejs sequelize loading nested models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**My mistake, question was incomplete, marking all missing text in bold**

I have following models:

- Patient
- **Personal**
- Address
- PatientAddress

---

- PatientAddress.belongsTo(Patient);
- **Patient.belongsTo(Personal);**
- PatientAddress.belongsTo(Address);

I'm trying to read patient and want to read address as well which looks like:

Patient => PatientAddress => Address

**I also need to read Personal model with Patient**

I can read **PatientAddress, Personal** using include but not able to read Address. I tried these:

```
return Patient.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    include: [{
        model: [Personal, PatientAddress],
        include: [{
            Address
        }]
    }]
});

return Patient.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    include: [{
        model: [Personal, PatientAddress],
        include: [{
            PatientAddress.Address
        }]
    }]
});
```

or

```
return Patient.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    include: [Personal, PatientAddress, PatientAddress.Address]
});
```

What to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested relations with Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282990/nested-relations-with-sequelize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Personal` is directly related to `Patient` but `Address` belongs to `PatientAddress`. Therefore you have to place the `Address`-include inside the include for `PatientAddress`, while `Personal`stays a first-level include.

```
return Patient.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    include: [
        {
            model: PatientAddress,
            include: [Address]
        },
        {
            model: Personal
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot simon.ro, this is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first query was pretty close, try this one:

```
return Patient.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    include: [
        {
            model: PatientAddress,
            include: [Address]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Yes, this works, I updated the missing piece in the question, I need to read the Personal model as well