# Include more than one model relationship in findAll

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to fetch some details from the database using `findAll` but I want to include a relationship from a model I added to the include statement.

I have a products table and I am fetching the products and include the user who posted the Item but this user has a profile so I want to include the users profile when I fetch products
something like

```
Product: {
  name: 'TV',
  User: {
    username:"someUserName",
    Profile: {
      image: 'a random image'
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to add the model to include but it doesn't work

```
const results = await Product.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: User,
        as: 'Seller',
        attributes:{
            exclude: ['password'],
        }
    }]
});
            return results;
```

Comment: isn't it a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282990/nested-relations-with-sequelize ?

Comment: my relation is not using id as the foreign key it uses the username how can I change it to point to that

Comment: see how foreign keys defined in the original question and specify username as shown there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `include` within the `include`. See below for implementation

```
const results = await Product.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: User,
    include: [ModelAssociatedToUser],
    as: 'Seller',
    attributes:{
      exclude: ['password'],
    }
  }],
});
```